# Relative volume increase of $\delta$-fattening of a compact set

Tags: measure-theory, inequalities, geometric-measure-theory

For a non-empty, compact set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the [$\delta$-fattening](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hausdorff_distance#/Definition) of $A$, $A_\delta$, is defined to be the set
$$
A_\delta = \cup_{a \in A} B_{\delta}(a),
$$
where $B_\delta(a)$ denotes the closed ball centered at $a$ with radius $\delta$.

Is it possible to establish an upper bound on $\mu(A_\delta)$ in terms of $\mu(A)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^n$?

In a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338941/525562), it was claimed that:

***Claim***
*Let $A$  be a nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mu(A)>0$. Then for all $\delta>0$* 
$$\mu(A_\delta)\le \left(1+\delta\,\frac{\lambda(\partial A)}{n\,\mu(A)}\right)^n\mu(A)\tag1,$$ where $A_\delta$ is the $\delta$-fattening of the set $A$, and $\lambda(\partial A)$ is the [Minkowski content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Steiner_formula)
$$\lambda(\partial A)=\liminf_{\delta\to 0}\delta^{-1}(\mu(A_\delta)-\mu(A))\tag2.$$
However, the proof utilized the fact that $f(\delta) = \left(\mu(A_\delta)/\mu(A)\right)^{1/n}$ is concave, which per [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641264/concavity-of-the-nth-root-of-the-volume-of-r-neighborhoods-of-a-set) is not true. Can the claim above or a similar inequality be established?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false in general. The example given by [George Lowther](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641264/concavity-of-the-nth-root-of-the-volume-of-r-neighborhoods-of-a-set) disproves it. Indeed, in that example, $n=2$ and $A$ is the union of the unit disk and a one-point set at distance $R>1$ from the origin, so that $\mu(A_\delta)=f(\delta):=\pi[(1+\delta)^2+\delta^2]$ for $\delta\in[0,(R-1)/2]$ and $\lambda(\partial A)=f'(0)=2\pi$. 
So, 
the ratio of the RHS of your proposed inequality (1) to its LHS is 
$$\frac{(1+\delta)^2}{(1+\delta)^2+\delta^2}<1$$
for $\delta\in(0,(R-1)/2]$.

Comment: Would some form of connectedness assumption about $A$ help here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the counterexample. As Igor also asked, is it possible to impose some sort of connectedness (or similar) assumption on the set $A$ so that the inequality (or a variant of it) holds? Another related question is whether enlarging the  $\delta\,\frac{\lambda(\partial A)}{n\,\mu(A)}$ term by a constant $c > 1$ would help establish an inequality that holds for all non-empty compact sets $A$? Intuitively, it seems to me that there must exist some inequality of the form $\mu(A_\delta) \leq g(\delta, A) \mu(A)$ for some function $g(\delta, A) \ge 1$.

Comment: Even the connectedness assumption and the extra factor $c>1$ cannot save the claim. See the "hedgehog" construction at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291646/relative-volume-increase-of-delta-fattening-of-a-connected-set/291647#291647